# API Price showing "undefined"

Tags: javascript, console.log

need help,
when i do this function get "undefined"

```
async function getPrice() {
  fetch('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=yfii-finance&vs_currencies=usd')
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data.yfii-finance.usd);
      getROI(data.yfii-finance.usd);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      error("something went wrong with fetch!");
    })
}
```

but when i changed to ethereum it's showing up the price

Comment: still not get the answer, maybe i think because the "-" at the id name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access the property with dot when it contains a dash.

You can access it with the bracket notation like so:

`data['yfii-finance'].usd`

[Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the response value by setting this snippet in your code.

```
data["yfii-finance"].usd

async function getPrice() {
  fetch('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=yfii-finance&vs_currencies=usd')
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      if(data['yfii-finance']) {
      console.log(data['yfii-finance'].usd);
      getROI(data['yfii-finance'].usd);
     }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      error("something went wrong with fetch!");
    })
}
```